# Can't reassign or increment variable (float)

Tags: javascript, jquery

At various points in this code, I am trying to increment pixelsSearchMoved by 1. Currently, according to the console.log it is stuck at 0.

And I know it is stuck at 0, because the code in the other conditions which require it to be 1 or greater are not being executed.

How can I get that variable to be incremented?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st <= lastScrollTop) {
        if (!isElementInViewport(document.getElementById('header'))) {
            var pixelsSearchMoved = 0;
            var pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop();
            while (pixelsSearchMoved <= 18) {
                var last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved;
                pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(pixelsSearchMoved === 0){
                    $('#searchInput').addClass('slideBack').css('top', '-22px');
                    console.log('pixelsSearchMoved is:'+pixelsSearchMoved);
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                else if (pixelsSearchMoved === 1) {
                    var x = '-22px';
                    $('#searchInput').css('top', parseFloat(x)+3+'px');
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                if (pixelsSearchMoved > 1 && (last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved + 1)) {
                    var x = $('#searchInput').css('top');
                    $('#searchInput').css('top', parseFloat(x)+3+'px');
                    console.log('moved up one!');
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                break;
            }
            $('#headerTopBar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            console.log('header in viewport');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Please post the source of your `isElementInViewport` function

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove break statement from the loop. 
It breaks the loop after first execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems I've noticed:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st <= lastScrollTop) {
        if (!isElementInViewport(document.getElementById('header'))) {
            // here you set pixelsSearchMoved = 0
            var pixelsSearchMoved = 0;
            var pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop(); // use st instead
            // 0 is always <= 18
            while (pixelsSearchMoved <= 18) {
                var last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved;
                pixelsScrollMoved = $(this).scrollTop(); // use st instead
                // this first condition is always true because you explicitly set pixelsSearchMoved to 0 above
                if (pixelsSearchMoved === 0) {
                    $('#searchInput').addClass('slideBack').css('top', '-22px');
                    console.log('pixelsSearchMoved is:' + pixelsSearchMoved);
                    // here you increment, but it's useless as the other conditions will never be executed
                    // and you explicitly drop out of your loop below
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                // this will never execute as you are not updating the value before the comparison
                else if (pixelsSearchMoved === 1) {
                    var x = '-22px';
                    $('#searchInput').css('top', parseFloat(x) + 3 + 'px'); // parseFloat('-22px') will always be -22, just use a static string instead
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                // the below will never execute as you've set last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved above
                // so it can never be last_pixelsScrollMoved = (pixelsScrollMoved + 1)
                // also, = is an assignment, == or === are comparisons
                if ((pixelsSearchMoved > 1) && (last_pixelsScrollMoved = pixelsScrollMoved + 1)) {
                    var x = $('#searchInput').css('top');
                    $('#searchInput').css('top', parseFloat(x) + 3 + 'px');
                    console.log('moved up one!');
                    pixelsSearchMoved++;
                }
                // drops you out of your loop
                break;
            }
            $('#headerTopBar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').fadeIn();
        } else {
            console.log('header in viewport');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

If you can post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the problem, we may be able to provide more insight.